# In Auth0, does each tenant have its own instance?

Tags: multi-tenant, auth0

I am reading the Auth0 'getting started' tutorial at this link: https://auth0.com/docs/getting-started/the-basics

It says the following:

"Once you create your account you will be asked to create a tenant. In Auth0, a tenant is a  **logical isolation unit** . The term is borrowed from  *software multitenancy*  and it refers to an architecture where a single instance of the software serves multiple tenants. No tenant can access the instance of another tenant, even though the software might be running on the same machine (hence the logical isolation)."

What I don't understand here is that it says "a single instance of the software serves multiple tenants" followed by "No tenant can access the instance of another tenant". So does each tenant have its own instance (implied by the second quote) or do multiple tenants share an instance (implied by the first quote)?

Also, my understanding of instances and tenants is that an instance is "a copy of the software with its own database", and a tenant corresponds to an account. So if each tenant has their own instance, does each user's account have its own database?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand each tenant exists in its own container. This helps to guarantee isolation. This would probably be what is meant by logical isolation unit.

Comment: Thanks @Dan Woda. I replied to your comment on the Auth0 Community group.